# Which attribute to use in System.ComponentModel namespace for setting order of fields?

Tags: .net, winforms, system.componentmodel

By default, the fields in the designer are listed in alphabetical order. Does anyone know which attribute to use in the `System.ComponentModel` namespace to set the order explicitly?

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Category] attribute to group properties so that the user can click the "Categorized" icon in the Properties window to arrange them.  Within a category, the names will still be sorted alphabetically.

The PropertyGrid.PropertySort property does have a setting for it (PropertySort.Categorized vs PropertySort.CategorizedAlphabetical) but the IDE's Properties window doesn't have an icon to choose between them.

Comment: I already have the Category attribute. Within the category, I'd like the properties not in the alphabetical order but the order I specify. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement ICustomTypeDescriptor and return the properties in the order you like. There is no guarantee the ui elements will honour that order.

Comment: I need the UI to honor the order. There are 2 options in the designer. One is A->Z option that sorts the properties alphabetically. When this is not selected, I need it in the order I specify explicitly. Currently it does alphabetical order by default. Will the ICustomTypeDescriptor solve this issue?